# How to debug a library in Eclipse ADT

Tags: java, android, eclipse, build

I have multiple projects with dependencies.

Project A depends on project B, which in turn depends on project C.
Project A is an application while project B and C are Android libraries.

I added them in my Java Build Path so that it builds correctly. I also checked them in "Order and Export".

However when I run my application, project B and C do not get copied to the device and result in a verification error. The only way I can get this to work is to manually copy the .jar files to A/libs. While this works, it is tedious to copy/rebuild every time I make the slightest change in B or C.

Is there a way to have them to be automatically resolved and uploaded to the device?

I am running the latest Eclipse ADT.

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem.  What is the error you're getting?  Is your project.properties being updated to contain the links to the library projects?  Also, have you tried including only B as a library in A, since C should come through via B?

Comment: I get a verify error, classes contained in B cannot be located by A

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the java files in project B and C are imported into the java files that depend on them in project A.

```
import com.example.projectb.SampleClass
```

This has always worked for me.

Comment: Yes I do this properly otherwise the project would not compile